# Jetpack Navigation : Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Jetpack navigation from the latest android architecture components in my app. In some rare cases, I get the following crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NewOfferFragment{40b548a} not attached to a context.
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:609)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:7673)
   at com.abc.xyz.offer.owner.fragment.NewOfferFragment$onActivityCreated$2.onChanged(NewOfferFragment.kt:1089)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:109)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:282)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations$2$1.onChanged(Transformations.java:145)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:109)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:282)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
   at com.abc.xyz.util.remoteUtils.NetworkBoundResource$fetchFromNetwork$2$2.com.abc.xyz.util.remoteUtils.Resource$Companion.error(NetworkBoundResource.kt:3019)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:109)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:121)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.access$000(LiveData.java:59)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.shouldBeActive(LiveData.java:416)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:207)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.plug(MediatorLiveData.java:141)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.addSource(MediatorLiveData.java:96)
   at com.abc.xyz.util.remoteUtils.NetworkBoundResource$fetchFromNetwork$2.onChanged(NetworkBoundResource.kt:1074)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:109)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:282)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:87)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The following is the code for my fragment's onActivityCreated:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[NewOfferViewModel::class.java]
    viewModel.init(offerId)

    binding?.let {
        it.viewModel = viewModel
        it.handler = RadioButtonHandler(this)
    }

    viewModel.result.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let {
            binding.resource = it
            endProgress()

            Logger.o(Thread.currentThread(), it)
            when (it.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    Logger.i(Thread.currentThread(), it.message)
                    endProgress()
                    if (viewModel.shouldUpload)
                        navController().popBackStack()
                    viewModel.shouldUpload = false
                }

                Status.ERROR -> {
                    Logger.i(Thread.currentThread(), it.message)
                    endProgress()
                    navController().popBackStack()
                    viewModel.shouldUpload = false
                }

                Status.LOADING -> {
                    startProgress()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Now I've seen a lot of solutions to the possible causes of this crash but those are for the traditional approach of inflating the fragment via a fragment manager. What might be the possible causes for this crash when using jetpack navigation?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your activity and fragment code.

Comment: Specifically, we need to see the `NewOfferFragment`'s `onActivityCreated` method with what lifecycle you're using with the LiveData.

Comment: I've edited the question with my fragment's onACtivityCreated.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue when observing on a livedata in a fragment navigated using jetpack navigation, are you able to reproduce it? For me, it happens from time to time and I haven't figured out what's causing it or how to reproduce it.

Comment: Ever find out the root cause of this? Experiencing the same thing with nav component and using live data as well. Cannot reproduce consistently but it does occur randomly on rotation.